# Concatenate one(!) row with separator

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, userform

I have following data:

```
Surname: John Walter Friedrich
Name: Waterford Harrington from Downhill
```

Each Word (separated by `" "`) in a new Column (here: "Surname:"=A1, "John"=B1, ... "Friedrich"=D1).

I have a Userform with textboxes.

What I want: Copy the Words from cells A1:(last not empty cell in row) into textbox in Userform.
-> Textbox filled with: `"John Walter Friedrich"` (separated by `" "`)

I tried various codes, but didn't found anything what matches my problem.

What I don't want: Combine rows! Thats what I found, but I have for one textbox just one row. So I dont want do go through each row until one is empty (because the next one is full).

PS: I can't get the data in my Excel sheet separated with `" "` to copy it. Problem: First Word (Surname or Name) should not be copied!

Comment: *"I tried various codes"* Please [edit] your question and add the code you have tried, so we can help you with that. Probably a screenshot of your sheet would clarify what is in which cell.

Comment: i'm sorry for the late answer, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim InputText As String
    InputText = "Surname: John Walter Friedrich"  'or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    MsgBox Right$(InputText, Len(InputText) - InStr(1, InputText, " "))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like this:

[image]

You can concatenate them by looping from column B to the last used column. To find the last used cell in a row use

```
Set LastUsedCellInRow = ws.Cells(RowNumber, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
```

So you end up with something like that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestConcat()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim RowNumber As Long
    RowNumber = 2

    Dim LastUsedCellInRow As Range
    Set LastUsedCellInRow = ws.Cells(RowNumber, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

    MsgBox ConcatenateSpaced(ws.Range("B" & RowNumber, LastUsedCellInRow))
End Sub

Public Function ConcatenateSpaced(InputRange As Range) As String
    If InputRange.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In InputRange
            ConcatenateSpaced = ConcatenateSpaced & " " & cell.Value
        Next cell
    End If

    ConcatenateSpaced = Trim$(ConcatenateSpaced)
End Function
```